# What is UITableViewCell imageView margin?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm creating a UITableView where some cells are just default cells (aka UITableViewCell(style: .default...), and some are custom cells which still have an image on the left and some other custom content on the right.  However, the images on the left of my custom cells have to align with default cells.

The issue I'm running into is that if I put in a custom imageView into a custom cell and give it a margin constraint of 16 to the leading edge it looks aligned with other cells on some devices such as iPhone 8.  But on larger devices it has to be 20 to align properly with standard imageView in the UITableViewCell(style: .default...)

Is there some standard way of doing this, if anyone solved this issue?  Or should I just simply not bother with apple provided cells, and make all custom cells to match image alignment?

Thank you.

Comment: Because it's so easy to create a custom cell similar to the default, I'd suggest yes, stick with custom cells. That way you know ***exactly*** what you're getting.

Comment: Alternatively, using `contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor` -- as in:  `myImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor) -- should give you the correct alignment.

Comment: Probably, you need to set `sizeForItemAt` to your UITableView.